# Incompatible java versions with Windows Builder in ECLIPSE

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jframe, windowbuilder

"Eclipse is running under 0, but this Java project has a 10 Java compliance level, so Window Builder will not be able to load classes from this project. Use a lower level of Java for the project, or run Eclipse using a newer Java version."

What do they mean by under 0 ?!
And how can I fix this?

Comment: You are running an old version of Eclipse that doesn't understand the version of Java that you have installed. Update to the latest Eclipse (2019-09, with 2019-12 due shortly)

Comment: That, or run it with OpenJDK 8.